# Is it possible to alter the font on a PCA plot created by plot.PCA() in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pca

How could I change the font on a plot.PCA() function of R?

I am doing the plot of the PCA of a given dataset, and I am trying to change the font of the plot, but it seems to be impossible.

```
plot.PCA(pca1, col.quali = 8, habillage = 8, label = "none", invisible = "quali", ggoptions = list(text.font = "Times"))
```

This is the result that I obtain:

[image]

The first five parameters are well-defined, and they only are related to the visualization of the PCA, not the font of the text. Could someone help me?

Comment: `?plot.PCA` will show you the documentation of this function, i.a.:
" **ggoptions** a list that gives the graph options
 *when graph.type="ggplot" is used*."